# Simplest and efficient way to check if a AzureTable has any data?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I would need a way to know the most efficient way to see if a table in azure storage has any data

Exemple

> cloudTable.ExecuteQuery("what do i do");

Thanks for the suggestions! I finally did something like this:

```
var query = new TableQuery<T>()
            {
                TakeCount = 1,
                SelectColumns = new List<string>()
                {
                    "PartitionKey"
                }
            };
var table = await this.GetTableAsync();
var segment = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

return segment.Results.Any();
```

Comment: The [documentation for TableQuery.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.where.aspx) says _"Setting a filter expression is optional; by default, all entities in the table are returned if no filter expression is specified in the table query."_ - whether this would be the most efficient way depends on how it's implemented in Azure. What problem is this intended to solve?

Comment: The table can be empty as well as contain hundred of thousands entries. I need it to be fast

Comment: Take(1)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.take.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this which limits your query to 1 record if there is data.

```
// select value = take smallest data field to avoid returning everything for a record
var query = new TableQuery().Select(new List<string>(){"smallcolumn"}).Take(1);
```

Comment: This question relates to Azure, not Entity Framework.